# Ionic 4 app not running in Android 9 and Android version lower then 7

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 project when i build my project for uploading on playstore i faced some issues. I add latest android platform in ionic app and build my app but when i run my app it only run on some specific versions of android like 7.1 and 8.0. App is not working on android 9 and Android version lower the 7.

Here is my Ionic info.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.0 (C:\Users\Muhammad Yaseen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.5.2
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Muhammad Yaseen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: can you be specific when you say not running? like only white screen, the app does not launch, or app cannot be installed.

Comment: if we talk about specific to 9.0, APK installed successfully and after running it shows Splash screen and home screen but whenever it needs to connect to server for data fetching or posting  its's keeps on loading and hangs after that. I have two apps one in ionic 3 and other in ionic 4 both have same problem in Android version 9.0

Comment: Voted to close this, because "not running" isn't an error description.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `<application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or as below using `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Comment: After adding these lines still not working on Android 9

Comment: this also is bad practice, especially when using plaintext for logins and alike.